# webview_flutter 3.0.4 - dark mode does not work

Tags: android, flutter, webview, themes, darkmode

I have a flutter app with a dark and light theme. The theme is selected according to the device theme or can be changed locally in the app. But **in webview the background is always light** and I don't know how to change the webview theme to dark. Do you have any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution that fixed my problem was injecting javascript as follows:

```
String js = "javascript: (function () { var css = 'html {-webkit-filter: invert(100%);' +    '-moz-filter: invert(100%);' +     '-o-filter: invert(100%);' +     '-ms-filter: invert(100%); }',head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],style = document.createElement('style');style.type = 'text/css';if (style.styleSheet){style.styleSheet.cssText = css;} else {style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));}head.appendChild(style);}());";


controller.runJavascript(js);
```

This code does color inversion, of course you can inject css via javascript and make more sophisticated changes.

Answer (score 0):

A webview is basically shows a website inside a container. The theme that you are managing in the app is not connected to the website you load in WebView. To change the theme of the website you should probably edit the website directly.